# Пересечения массивов с хэшами

Tags: ruby

Есть 2 массива из хэшей. Хэши в массивах имеют различную структуру, но имеют несколько одинаковых ключей:

```
arr1 = [
  {'a'=> 1, 'b'=>2, 'c'=>3 },
  {'a'=> 2, 'b'=>4, 'c'=>5 },
]

arr2 = [
  {'a'=> 1, 'b'=>2, 'd'=>300, 'f'=>"abc"},
  {'a'=> 1, 'b'=>4, 'd'=>500, 'f'=>"def"},
  {'a'=> 2, 'b'=>10, 'd'=>100, 'f'=>"ghi"},
]
```

Как можно найти пересечения и расхождения этих массивов по a, b, и (a и b)?

Примеры желаемого результата:

arr2 - arr1 по a:

```
[]
```

arr2 && arr1 по a:

```
[
  {'a'=> 1, 'b'=>2, 'd'=>300, 'f'=>"abc"},
  {'a'=> 1, 'b'=>4, 'd'=>500, 'f'=>"def"},
  {'a'=> 2, 'b'=>10, 'd'=>100, 'f'=>"ghi"}
]
```

arr2 - arr1 по b:

```
[
  {'a'=> 2, 'b'=>10, 'd'=>100, 'f'=>"ghi"}
]
```

arr2 && arr1 по b:

```
[
  {'a'=> 1, 'b'=>2, 'd'=>300, 'f'=>"abc"},
  {'a'=> 1, 'b'=>4, 'd'=>500, 'f'=>"def"}
]
```

arr1 - arr2 по a + b:

```
[
  {'a'=> 1, 'b'=>4, 'd'=>500, 'f'=>"def"},
  {'a'=> 2, 'b'=>10, 'd'=>100, 'f'=>"ghi"}
]
```

arr1 && arr2 по a + b:

```
[
  {'a'=> 1, 'b'=>2, 'd'=>300, 'f'=>"abc"}
]
```

Comment: Приведите пример результата, который хотите получить.

Comment: добавил примеры

Comment: Окей. Так понятнее. А что именно у вас не получается?

Comment: как сравнить 2 массива с хэшами одинаковой структуры я понимаю. а вот как по отделльным ключам сравнивать нет(

Comment: Ну вместо `x == y` будет `f(x) == f(y)`, подумаешь .-.

Comment: если можно, для тех кто в танке, пример на пальцах?)

Comment: `x = {a: 1, b: 2}; y = {a: 1, c: 3}; f = ->(c) { c[:a] }; f.(x) == f.(y) # => true` пример сравнения только по `:a`, например. Операции с множествами в этом случае придётся писать руками, но они тривиальные, с `Enumerable`-то. Есть и другой путь, конечно -- определить класс с другим методом равенства и орудовать массивами из объектов этого класса. Выбирайте.

Comment: ок. спасибо за развернутый ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всегда можно реализовать эти операции самостоятельно, с помощью `Enumerable`. Но это же неинтересно, верно?

У массивов есть методы `&` и `|`, которые делают то, что вам нужно, используя методы `hash` и `eql?` у объектов-элементов. Вот только они определены у `Hash` так, что сравнивают **все** ключи. Можно определить собственный тип-обёртку, который сравнивает, скажем, только по ключу `:a`:

```
EqualByA = Struct.new(:value) do # Чтоб не копаться с initialize, @value = value и т. п.
  # Вернуть значение, по которому будет производиться сравнение на равенство.
  def key
    value[:a]
  end

  # Точное равенство
  def eql?(rhs)
    key.eql? rhs.key
  end

  # Для быстрой гарантированной проверки на НЕравенство
  def hash
    key.hash
  end
end

x = EqualByA.new(a: 1, b: 2)
y = EqualByA.new()
p ([x] | [y]).map(&:value) # !> [{:a=>1, :b=>2}]
p ([y] & [z]).map(&:value) # !> [{:a=>1, :y=>4}]
p ([x] - [y]).map(&:value) # !> []
```

Опционально:

- Можно сделать этот класс абстрактным по методу `key` и использовать наследование, чтобы получить значения, сравниваемые по другим критериям. Отдельное внимание в этом случае стоит уделить сравнению подобных объектов разных типов.
- Можно определить `<=>`, делегировать ключу, чтобы по значению `key` можно было сортировать.
- Можно сделать метод класса, принимающий блок для `key` и возвращающий новый класс на манер того, что выше. Используемый как-то так: `EqlByA = EqualBy.proc { |x| x[:a] }`

Comment: нешел еще 1 решение https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494890/ruby-compare-two-arrays-of-hash-with-certain-keys